# TreeViewItem with ItemsSource Right-Click doesn't select the Item

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, selecteditem

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityType:FixedDevice}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" Handler="TreeViewItem_RightClick"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<TreeViewItem Header="Data Warehouse">
    <TreeViewItem.Items>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Platforms">
            <TreeViewItem.Items>
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Path=Parent.Items.Count,
                                   StringFormat=Public ({0})}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </TreeViewItem.Header>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem.Items>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem.Items>
</TreeViewItem>

 private void TreeViewItem_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
      if(item != null) { item.Focus(); item.IsSelected = true; }
      e.Handled = true;
 }
```

How come when I right-click, it only selects the top-most node? and not the one I click? Similar for an `ItemsSource`, which the `Item` itself is not a `TreeViewItem`, but a `DataTemplate` with a `TextBlock`, how do I select the object in the TreeView visually?

Edit, see below for answer based on @Viv answer.
I ended up having to use `e.OriginalSource` to retrieve the `TextBlock` then the `TreeViewItem` that the `Item` was in.

```
private void TreeViewItem_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    TreeViewItem item = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Parent as TreeViewItem;
    if(item == null) {
        item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        if(item == null) {
            return;
        }
    }
    item.IsSelected = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because what your looking for is `e.Source` and not `sender`

try switching your right-click handler to:

```
private void TreeViewItem_RightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  TreeViewItem item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
  if (item == null)
    return;
  // item.Focus();
  item.IsSelected = true;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

[Sample Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/133pnsm7nhhjjg9/WpfApplication47.rar)

Comment: I tried doing that, and it still gave me the same result. `e.Source` is the same as `sender`.

Comment: @Bob. err not for me I can reproduce your issue only if in the handler I use `sender`. `e.Source` is fine. I've added a sample to the answer. Try that and see if that works fine for you or do you see the same issue even in that project

Comment: Okay, I figured out where exactly the problem was, it is in the `TreeViewItem.Header`, if it isn't set as `Header="Text Here"`, it doesn't respond to the click (see above edit for `TreeViewItem.Header`), but the `Items` inside do, with the `e.Source` being the first node after root.

Comment: I ended up having to use `e.OriginalSource` to get the `TextBlock` to retrieve the `TreeViewItem` that was clicked.